# Wmctrl Resizing Issue

Tags: wmctrl

The following fails to resize my active window (simply nothing happens).  Is there something I'm missing?

The command I used is:

```
wmctrl -r -e :ACTIVE: 0,100,100,600,400
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You syntax for the command is wrong, use:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,100,100,600,400
```

The `-r` parameter expects a window name string (or `:ACTIVE:`) and the `-e` paramter expects the dimensions.

Comment: This works great (!).  But now I have a new issue: once I resize a window, if I use compiz to "put right" or "put left", I'm no longer able to use this command to resize the window.  Does this mean I should just use wmctrl to resize windows?

Comment: @George I don't encounter this problem. After I resized the window manually (by mouse) I'm able to resize it also with that command.

Comment: Resizing with a mouse works for me as well.  But it's when I use the compiz commands to place a window in the left or right portion of the screen (technically the "grid" command; I mispoke earlier about saying it was the "put" command), I'm then unable to resize the window using the wmctrl command.